# Windows Universal APP - Window Title Bar in fullscreen

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I'm developing a C#/XAML Windows 10 Universal App (to my understanding this is practically WinRt platform). For now I'm concerned with desktop runtime environment - even though my app is in fullscreen mode, when I move mouse pointer to the top of the screen application a standard window title bar shows up. This behaviour is annoying because is inconsistent with my UI design, is it possible to change this behaviour?

Comment: Why do you think it is inconsistent? Consider that all other apps will behave this way. Also what change do you desire?

Answer (score 1):

No it cannot be disabled, but it will only show up when you’re in desktop mode (using a mouse). On the other hand, when you’re in mobile mode (using touch mode), the title bar will not show up. The reason it’s there is because lots of people with a mouse complained that there was not any easy way to minimize or to close the application.

If you feel that it’s annoying and doesn’t match with your design, unfortunately you may have to change your design a bit.

Comment: Yes, as I user of an app I would very happy knowing that I can always minimize the app, for example if it freezed/hanged or for any other reason wouldn't let me to exit it so I understand the assumption that was taken. On the other hand I think that in WPF or DX application I could could achieve the behavior that I want, so I think it's not bad design of the framework and I won't complain.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround that almost lets me achieve effect that I desired - changing default style of application's titlebar to transparent. After doing this, when user swipes mouse to application's upper edge, only something like one pixel thick blue line will upper on the upper edge.

```cs
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().
        TitleBar.ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;

    var titleBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.
        GetForCurrentView().TitleBar;

    var transparent = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent;

    titleBar.BackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ForegroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonHoverForegroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonPressedForegroundColor = transparent;
    titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = transparent;
```

Now, the interesting question would be how to achieve similar effect with task bar.